# Joining dataframes, overwriting x with y if y has value

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes

DF x:

```
ID  A  B  C
1   x  y  z
2   x  y  z
```

DF y:

```
ID  A  B  C
1   NA d  f
2   e  NA NA
```

I want to join them in such way that the value of x gets overwritten by the value of y, but only if there is a value in y for the matching column in x.

Hence, the outcome of the above should be:

```
ID  A  B  C
1   x  d  f
2   e  y  z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(dfx, dfy, by = 'ID') %>%
   transmute(ID, A = coalesce(A.y, A.x),
                 B = coalesce(B.y, B.x),
                 C = coalesce(C.y, C.x))
#   ID A B C
#1  1 x d f
#2  2 e y z
```

Or if there are many columns, reshape it to 'long' format, do the `coalesce` and then reshape into 'wide' format

```
library(tidyr)
left_join(dfx, dfy, by = 'ID') %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = c("group", ".value"), names_sep = "\\.") %>% 
   mutate(x = coalesce(y, x)) %>%
   select(-y) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = x)
```

---

Or another option is to `bind_rows` the two datasets  and then do a `group_by` `summarise` (assuming one row per 'ID')

```
bind_rows(dfy, dfx) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~ first(.[!is.na(.)]))
```

---

Or using a join `on` data.table

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- names(dfx)[-1]
nm2 <- paste0("i.", nm1)
setDT(dfy)[dfx, (nm1) := Map(coalesce, mget(nm1), mget(nm2)), on = .(ID)]

dfy
```

#### data

```
dfx <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, A = c("x", "x"), B = c("y", "y"), C = c("z", 
"z")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

dfy <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, A = c(NA, "e"), B = c("d", NA), C = c("f", 
NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R, we can get the index of non-NA values in `dfy` and replace the corresponding values of `dfx` with it.

```
#Rearrange dfy if you have columns in different order than dfx
#dfy <- dfy[names(dfx)] 
inds <- which(!is.na(dfy[-1]), arr.ind = TRUE)
dfx[-1][inds] <- dfy[-1][inds]
dfx

#  ID A B C
#1  1 x d f
#2  2 e y z
```